# Can I run 'su' in the middle of a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

Can I change/su user in the middle of a script?

```
if [ "$user" == "" ]; then
  echo "Enter the table name";
  read user
fi

gunzip *
chown postgres *
su postgres 
dropdb $user
psql -c "create database $user with encoding 'unicode';" -U dbname template1
psql -d $user -f *.sql
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use su to execute the rest of the bash script as that user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988249/how-do-i-use-su-to-execute-the-rest-of-the-bash-script-as-that-user)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can, but bash won't run the subsequent commands as postgres. Instead, do:

```
su postgres -c 'dropdb $user'
```

The `-c` flag runs a command as the user (see `man su`).

Comment: You'd want to use double quotes there: `su postgres -c "dropdb $user"`

Comment: You can put multiple lines if the closing quote comes on another line. Take care of quoting in that case.

Answer (score 38):

You can use a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heredoc) to embed multiple `su` commands in your script:

```
if [ "$user" == "" ]; then
  echo "Enter the table name";
  read user
fi

gunzip *
chown postgres *
su postgres <<EOSU
dropdb $user
psql -c "create database $user with encoding 'unicode';" -U dbname template1
psql -d $user -f *.sql
EOSU
```

Comment: Be careful, I think some characters, like backtick, need to be escaped if you put them in a here document.

Comment: Also be careful that all variables in the heredoc are substituted *before* passing it to `su`. This can be a problem when you create and use variables inside. To avoid that, turn off parameter substitution by surrounding the first `EOSU` with single quotes, like so: `su postgres <<'EOSU'`

Comment: Note that `==` isn't guaranteed to work inside `[`. The only standard-mandated string comparison operator is `=`

Answer (score 14):

Not like this. `su` will invoke a process, which defaults to a shell. On the command line, this shell will be interactive, so you can enter commands. In the context of a script, the shell will end right away (because it has nothing to do).

With

```
su user -c command
```

`command` will be executed as `user` - if the `su` succeeds, which is generally only the case with password-less users or when running the script as root.

Use `sudo` for a better and more fine-grained approach.

Answer (score 7):

Refer to answers in below question,

You can write between << EOF and EOF as mentioned in answers.

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami
sudo -u someuser bash << EOF
echo "In"
whoami
EOF
echo "Out"
whoami
```

[How do I use su to execute the rest of the bash script as that user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988249/how-do-i-use-su-to-execute-the-rest-of-the-bash-script-as-that-user)

Comment: Add -i to sudo to get someuser's environment.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't. Or atleast... you can su but su will simply open a new shell at that point and when it's done it will continue with the rest of the script.

One way around it is to use `su -c 'some command'`

Answer (score 2):

Another interesting idea that I heard today is to do a recursive call on the script, when you run as root and you want to run the script as another user. See the example below:

I am running script "my_script" as "root" and want the script to run as user "raamee"

---

```
#!/bin/bash

#Script name is: my_script

user=`whoami`

if [ "$user" == "root" ]; then
  # As suggested by glenn jackman. Since I don't have anything to run once 
  # switching the user, I can modify the next line to: 
  # exec sudo -u raamee my_script and reuse the same process
  sudo -u raamee my_script
fi

if [ "$user" == "raamee" ]; then
  #put here the commands you want to perform
  do_command_1
  do_command_2
  do_command_3
fi
```

Comment: If you have nothing to do after "raamee" does work, then you can: `exec sudo -u raamee my_script` -- that replaces the current process instead of keeping it hanging around.

Comment: Clever, but a here document is simpler (see my answer).

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with this is the sudo`d user (if not root) needs to have permissions to run the script itself.