# Unix: ‘su user’ not working and remains root inside SSH if condition

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, command-line, su

I've been working on bash script and have encoutered strange issue. Basically, I SSH into remote server as root from local server and trying to run some commands. One of the commands is changing the user to service account from root. For that I use command "su " and it changes to service account. But strangely, when I run the same command inside 'if condition', it remains as root account only. Here's the snippet of the code:

```
  echo "Enter host name you want to start: "
  read remote

  echo "Enter password for $remote : "
  read -s remote_pass

  sshpass -p$remote_pass ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $remote <<EOF
      ps -ef | grep -i tomcat | grep -i bootstrap | awk '{print \$2}'

      if [ -z "\$(ps -ef | grep -i tomcat | awk '{print \$2}')" ]
        then
          echo "$remote: Need to start server"
          su serviceAccount -----------> This doesn't work inside if controller
          startup.sh ---------> I want to run this script using serviceAccount and not as root!!!
        else
          echo "$remote: Already up and running"
      fi
      echo "#######################################################"
      echo
EOF
```

Please help!

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not strange but expected. `su` is not some kind of magic toggle, instead it spawns a new process with elevated rights. Everything you would like to do as `serviceAccount` needs to be done within the `su` call.

For non-interactive use like in your example, the `-c` option comes handy:

```
su -c 'startup.sh' serviceAccount
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'm fairly new on this. I have a question, when in do 'su'  before the if loop, the whole code below works as serviceAccount. But not when I log inside the if loop. That's what I found strange.

Comment: It would work the way you describe if you put the `su`command in front of your '<<EOF'. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420280/can-i-run-su-in-the-middle-of-a-bash-script