# running expect scripts that are in gist.github.com

Tags: bash, expect, gist

I know I can run bash scripts placed inside gist.github.com using the following:

```
bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/5126919)" <arg0> <arg1>
```

How do I do the same for expect scripts?

I have a sample here:

https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/5126919

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set CHANGESHELL_FOR_USER [lindex $argv 0];
set PASSWORD_OF_USER [lindex $argv 1];

########################################
## switch to another user
## read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1988255/80353
########################################
sudo -u $CHANGESHELL_FOR_USER -H sh -c "chsh -s /bin/bash" 

expect "*?assword:*" {send -- "$PASSWORD_OF_USER\r";}
expect eof
```

My purpose is to chsh for a particular user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash and ksh support process substitution so you can try like this:

`expect <(curl ...) arg1 arg2 ...`

The only problem I can think of is that the value of `$argv0` is not what we usually expect. You may consider hard coding it in the script.