# Can I switch user in Vagrant bootstrap shell script?

Tags: shell, vagrant

**Edit** Apparently, the problem was that I should have done
`su - postgres -c "commands, commands, commands"`,
that is, passed any commands to `su`, rather than attempting to list them below `su`, because those commands (below `su`) aren't affected by `su`. **/Edit**

**Edit 2:** See David Braun's answer for an even better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22947716/694469

---

Can I not switch user (`su - postgres`) in a Vagrant bootstrap shell provisioning script? (Why not?)

I'm writing such a script. In that script, I do:

```
echo '===== Creating PostgreSQL databases and users'

su - postgres

psql -c "
  create user SomeUserName password '...';
  alter user ...;
  "
```

Here, `psql` should attempt to login as user `postgres`. What happens, however, is that `su - postgres` apparently fails, and the shell attempts to login as user *root*. (Apparently, *root* is the user that runs the Vagrant bootstrap shell script.)

So this error appears and the psql commands aren't invoked:

> psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

Replacing `su - postgres` with `sudo su - postgres` has no effect (I think the script is already run as *root*.)

I added `id` (which prints the current user ID) before and after `su - postgres`, and `id` prints `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)` both before and after `su` was called. So as far as I can tell, `su - postgres` is kind of ignored? And a certain `exit`, later on when I attempt to switch back to the *root* user, exits the bootstrap script completely :-(

However. After doing `vagrant ssh`, I'm able to `sudo su - postgres` just fine, and then start `psql`. But not from within the provisioning script.

(A workaround is to specify `-h 127.0.0.1 --username postgres` when I call `psql` (instead of switching user to *postgres*). And also enable PostgreSQL trust based authentication for VM local connections.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can switch users in Vagrant shell scripts as that might require user input which you cannot give it when the script is running in the provisioner... but why not just specify the user with the psql command?

```
psql --username=postgres -c "..."
```

Comment: Re: "as that might require user input" — Okay, I didn't think about that. So if I had specified `--command COMMAND` as a `su` option, I might have gotten everything to work, eventually. I suppose that explains it all, and the problem was that I'm not too familiar with Bash, rather than anything related to Vagrant. (?)

Comment: Thanks for the `--username` suggestion. (I did mention at the end of the question that: "A workaround is to specify `-h 127.0.0.1 --username postgres`".)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just saw you mentioned the username part as well... jumped into the answer too quickly hehe...

Answer (score 25):

```
echo '===== Creating PostgreSQL databases and users'

su postgres << EOF
psql -c "
  create user SomeUserName password '...';
  alter user ...;
  "
EOF
```

Comment: Nice, and it works I tested :-) I added a link from the question itself.

Comment: I received an
ERROR:  CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string

Answer (score 14):

I just found this while looking for a way to run Vagrant provider scripts as non-root, and would like to add an explanation for the observed behaviour, which is quite fundamental Unix knowledge that would be useful for readers to know.

Running a program (such as /bin/sh, sudo or su) in a shell script cannot change anything in the context (working directory, running user etc) in which it runs, only set the context for the process it creates (and only change the running uid if running as root - uid 0). This is also why cd is a builtin command in shells. su is a setuid program (note the "s" when you try the command "ls -l `which su`") which means that it will run as the user owning the program (root) rather than as the user running it.

Comment: And this is how you work around it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988249/how-do-i-use-su-to-execute-the-rest-of-the-bash-script-as-that-user

Answer (score 10):

LHP is right: it is not really a vagrant issue. I needed to do that some time ago and here is how I've solved it:

```
#!/bin/bash

case $(id -u) in
    0) 
         echo first: running as root
         echo doing the root tasks...
         sudo -u vagrant -i $0  # script calling itself as the vagrant user
         ;;
    *) 
         echo then: running as vagrant user
         echo doing the vagrant user's tasks
         ;;
esac
```

Maybe this could be useful for someone, but another obvious solution will be just run a second script using sudo.

FIXED: Thank you Macattack. I wrote directly in stackoverflow and it still not tested.

EDIT: The question has been edited and now its description, and most of the answers, are focusing on "How to create a postgres database with the right user" rather than how to switch user in a vagrant script.

Comment: You're missing the `;;` at the end of each `case`. Other than that, great solution, was just what I was looking for.

Comment: use `"` at line `echo doing the vagrant user's tasks`! The correct syntax would be `echo "doing the vagrant user's tasks"`

Comment: @Doka: despite that being completely irrelevant I don't see any documentation supporting your claim