# How to get $HOME directory when switching to a different user in bash?

Tags: bash

I need to execute part of a bash script as a different user, and inside that user's `$HOME` directory. However, I'm not sure how to determine this variable. Switching to that user and calling `$HOME` does not provide the correct location:

```
# running script as root, but switching to a different user...
su - $different_user
echo $HOME
# returns /root/ but should be /home/myuser
```

#### Update:

It appears that the issue is with the way that I am trying to switch users in my script:

```
$different_user=deploy

# create user
useradd -m -s /bin/bash $different_user

echo "Current user: `whoami`"
# Current user: root

echo "Switching user to $different_user"
# Switching user to deploy

su - $different_user
echo "Current user: `whoami`"
# Current user: root
echo "Current user: `id`"
# Current user: uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

sudo su $different_user
# Current user: root
# Current user: uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

What is the correct way to switch users and execute commands as a different user in a bash script?

Comment: You can always extract it from /etc/passwd, assuming it's a locally defined account.

Comment: `su - $different_user` should have been enough. Are you sure you're even logged in as `myuser`. Try running `id` command to verify. Some login shell is set to `nologin` and it exits as soon you login as `myuser`.

Comment: @anubhava I updated my question to include how I created the user. Essentially: `useradd -m -s /bin/bash $different_user`.

Comment: Please take another look at my answer. I substantially changed it to match exactly what you have attempted to do.

Comment: Please do not use `eval` or `bash -c` with a variable. I added an answer that works safely for an Linux/Unix/macOS system with bash (even if you are not using bash as your shell, it likely has bash available because bashisms are everywhere). https://stackoverflow.com/a/53219743/117471 It also explains the danger of other answers.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

**Update**: Based on this question's title, people seem to come here **just looking for a way to *find* a different user's home directory, without the need to *impersonate* that user**.

In that case, the simplest solution is to use **[tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) with the username of interest, combined with `eval`** (which is needed, because the username must be given as an *unquoted literal* in order for tilde expansion to work):

```
eval echo "~$different_user"    # prints $different_user's home dir.
```

Note: The **usual [caveats regarding the use of `eval`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) apply**; in this case, the assumption is that you control the value of `$different_user` and know it to be a mere username.

By contrast, the remainder of this answer deals with ***impersonating* a user *and* performing operations *in that user's home directory***.

---

Note:

- Administrators by default and other users if authorized via the `sudoers` file can impersonate other users via `sudo`.
- The following is based on the *default* configuration of `sudo` - changing its configuration can make it behave differently - see `man sudoers`.

The **basic form** of executing a command as another user is:

```
sudo -H -u someUser someExe [arg1 ...]
  # Example:
sudo -H -u root env  # print the root user's environment
```

Note:

- **If you neglect to specify `-H`, the impersonating process (the process invoked in the context of the specified user) will report the *original* user's home directory in `$HOME`.**
- The impersonating process will have the same working directory as the invoking process.
- The impersonating process performs **no shell expansions** on string literals passed as arguments, since no shell is involved in the impersonating process (unless `someExe` happens to be a shell) - expansions by the *invoking* shell - prior to passing to the impersonating process - can obviously still occur.

Optionally, you can have an impersonating process **run as or via a(n impersonating) shell**, by prefixing `someExe` either with `-i` **or** `-s` - not specifying `someExe ...` creates an **interactive** shell:

- `-i` creates a **login** shell for `someUser`, which implies the following:

  - `someUser`'s *user-specific shell profile, if defined, is loaded*.
  - `$HOME` points to `someUser`'s home directory, so there's **no need for `-H`** (though you may still specify it)
  - The working directory for the impersonating shell is the `someUser`'s home directory.
- `-s` creates a non-login shell:

  - no shell *profile* is loaded (though initialization files for interactive *nonlogin* shells are; e.g., `~/.bashrc`)
  - **Unless you also specify `-H`, the impersonating process will report the *original* user's home directory in `$HOME`.**
  - The impersonating shell will have the same working directory as the invoking process.

Using a shell means that string arguments passed on the command line MAY be **subject to shell expansions** - *see platform-specific differences below* - by the impersonating shell (possibly after initial expansion by the invoking shell); compare the following two commands (which use *single* quotes to prevent premature expansion by the *invoking* shell):

```
  # Run root's shell profile, change to root's home dir.
sudo -u root -i eval 'echo $SHELL - $USER - $HOME - $PWD'
  # Don't run root's shell profile, use current working dir.
  # Note the required -H to define $HOME as root`s home dir.
sudo -u root -H -s eval 'echo $SHELL - $USER - $HOME - $PWD'
```

**What shell** is invoked is determined by "the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell as specified in passwd(5)" (according to `man sudo`). Note that with `-s` it is the *invoking* user's environment that matters, whereas with `-i` it is the *impersonated* user's.

Note that there are **platform differences regarding shell-related behavior (with `-i` or `-s`)**:

- **`sudo` on Linux apparently only accepts an *executable or builtin* name as the *first* argument following `-s`/`-i`**, whereas OSX allows passing an entire shell command line; e.g., OSX accepts `sudo -u root -s 'echo $SHELL - $USER - $HOME - $PWD'` directly (no need for `eval`), whereas Linux doesn't (as of `sudo 1.8.95p`).
- **Older versions of `sudo` on Linux do NOT apply shell expansions to arguments passed to a shell**; for instance, with `sudo 1.8.3p1` (e.g., Ubuntu 12.04), `sudo -u root -H -s echo '$HOME'` simply echoes the string literal "$HOME" instead of expanding the variable reference in the context of the root user. As of at least `sudo 1.8.9p5` (e.g., Ubuntu 14.04) this has been fixed. Therefore, to ensure expansion on Linux even with older `sudo` versions, pass the the entire command as a single argument to `eval`; e.g.: `sudo -u root -H -s eval 'echo $HOME'`. (Although not necessary on OSX, this will work there, too.)
- The `root` user's `$SHELL` variable contains `/bin/sh` on OSX 10.9, whereas it is `/bin/bash` on Ubuntu 12.04.

Whether the impersonating process involves a shell or not, its environment will have the following variables set, reflecting the invoking user and command: `SUDO_COMMAND`, `SUDO_USER`, `SUDO_UID=`, `SUDO_GID`.

See `man sudo` and `man sudoers` for many more subtleties.

Tip of the hat to  @DavidW and @Andrew for inspiration.

Comment: With `getent` you don't need `eval`.

Answer (score 29):

In BASH, you can find a user's `$HOME` directory by prefixing the user's login ID with a tilde character. For example:

```
$ echo ~bob
```

This will echo out user `bob`'s `$HOME` directory.

However, you say you want to be able to execute a script as a particular user. To do that, you need to setup [sudo](http://man.cx/sudo). This command allows you to execute particular commands as either a particular user. For example, to execute `foo` as user `bob`:

```
$ sudo -i -ubob -sfoo
```

This will start up a new shell, and the `-i` will simulate a login with the user's default environment and shell (which means the `foo` command will execute from the `bob's`$HOME` directory.)

Sudo is a bit complex to setup, and you need to be a superuser just to be able to see the shudders file (usually `/etc/sudoers`). However, this file usually  has several examples you can use.

In this file, you can specify the commands you specify who can run a command, as which user, and whether or not that user has to enter their password before executing that command. This is normally the default (because it proves that this is the user and not someone who came by while the user was getting a Coke.) However, when you run a shell script, you usually want to disable this feature.

Comment: Promising, but `-i` and `-s` appear to be mutually exclusive. Just `-i` should be enough.

Comment: Having trouble assigning `~$different_user` to a variable and turning it into `$HOME`. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Andrew Don't use quotation marks! `user_home=~$different_user`. Note there's no quotation marks around the `~$different_user`.  Your OS may also prevent you from reassigning `HOME` since it does have special meaning. Are you using `sudo`? That's the recommended way.

Answer (score 25):

For the sake of an alternative answer for those searching for a lightweight way to just find a user's home dir...

Rather than messing with `su` hacks, or bothering with the overhead of launching another `bash` shell just to find the `$HOME` environment variable...

#### Lightweight Simple Homedir Query via Bash

There is a command specifically for this: **`getent`**

`getent passwd someuser | cut -f6 -d:`

`getent` can do a lot more... just see the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getent).  The `passwd` nsswitch database will return the user's entry in `/etc/passwd` format.  Just split it on the colon `:` to parse out the fields.

It should be installed on most Linux systems (or any system that uses [GNU Lib C](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (RHEL: `glibc-common`, Deb: `libc-bin`)

Comment: `getent` is specific to Linux, as you state; a simpler and platform-neutral way is to use bash's  [tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) with the username of interest (`eval` is needed, because the user name must be given as an _unquoted literal_ for the expansion to work): `eval echo "~$different_user"` - the usual caveats re use of `eval` apply.

Comment: Very good idea to let bash do it!  Another alternative for current user home is: `eval echo "~$(who -m | awk '{ print $1 }')"` or simply `eval echo "~"`.   On Mac OS X, there is the `dscl` utility, but it's output is much harder to parse, and requires you to already pass in the `/Users` homedir or uid (e.g.: `dscl . -read /Users/$(who -m | awk '{ print $1 }')`  or `dscl . -search /Users UniqueID $(id -u)`).  It's probably easier on some platforms to just use bash, or do some sort of basic OS detection anyway.

Comment: For the current user, you do not need `eval` at all: unquoted `~` will return the current user's home directory (e.g. `echo ~`). If you really need the current user's username explicitly, `$USER` is simplest, efficient, and POSIX-compliant; `whoami` is also simple, but comparatively expensive and non-POSIX. Your `who -m`-based command, while POSIX-compliant, is even more expensive. To conclude: yes, using a POSIX-compatible shell (e.g., Bash) is simplest, most efficient and portable.

Comment: `getent` is specific to Linux, but why? It seems to an evidently useful thing to have (basically a command-line interface to query a database, albeit one implemented via text files) and should be easily portable, too. Well, it should additionally have a way to extract values from the record. This would avoid the roundabout use of `cut`

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: The reason for `getent` instead of just reading from `/etc/passwd` is because of the potential for different sources of user & login authentication data backend.  There are a variety of backends for user database such as  `sssd` (sss/LDAP), NIS, and NIS+.  For more information on this, please see [this SE Answer about nsswitch.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171827/7688).  The need for the extra cut is not the greatest I'd agree, but it's what the tool outputs.  The real reason for using `getent` is to try to query the configured user database backend on the system.

Answer (score 5):

The title of this question is **How to get $HOME directory of different user in bash script?** and that is what people are coming here from Google to find out.

## There is a safe way to do this!

### on Linux/BSD/macOS/OSX without sudo or root

```sh
user=pi
user_home=$(bash -c "cd ~$(printf %q $USER) && pwd")
```

**NOTE:** The reason this is safe is because bash (even versions prior to 4.4) has its own `printf` function that includes:

> `%q   quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input`

See: `help printf`

#### Compare the how other answers here respond to code injection

```sh
# "ls /" is not dangerous so you can try this on your machine
# But, it could just as easily be "sudo rm -rf /*"
$ user="root; ls /"
$ printf "%q" "$user"
root\;\ ls\ /

# This is what you get when you are PROTECTED from code injection
$ user_home=$(bash -c "cd ~$(printf "%q" "$user") && pwd"); echo $user_home
bash: line 0: cd: ~root; ls /: No such file or directory

# This is what you get when you ARE NOT PROTECTED from code injection
$ user_home=$(bash -c "cd ~$user && pwd"); echo $user_home
bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 media mnt ono opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var /root

$ user_home=$(eval "echo ~$user"); echo $user_home
/root bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 media mnt ono opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var
```

### on Linux/BSD/macOS/OSX as root

If you are doing this because you are running something as `root` then you can use the power of sudo:

```sh
user=pi
user_home=$(sudo -u $user sh -c 'echo $HOME')
```

### on Linux/BSD (but not modern macOS/OSX) without sudo or root

If not, the you can get it from `/etc/passwd`. There are already lots of examples of using `eval` and `getent`, so I'll give another option:

```sh
user=pi
user_home=$(awk -v u="$user" -v FS=':' '$1==u {print $6}' /etc/passwd)
```

I would really only use that one if I had a bash script with lots of other awk oneliners and no uses of `cut`. While many people like to "code golf" to use the fewest characters to accomplish a task, I favor "tool golf" because using fewer tools gives your script a smaller "compatibility footprint". Also, it's less man pages for your coworker or future-self to have to read to make sense of it.

Comment: +1 for pointing out some of the caveats of other proposals  Others have just said that the usual caveats apply for eval - but it's often hard for people to imagine what that means.

Answer (score 3):

You want the `-u` option for `sudo` in this case. From the `man` page:

```
The -u (user) option causes sudo to run the specified command as a user other than root.
```

If you don't need to actually run it as them, you could move to their home directory with `~<user>`. As in, to move into my home directory you would use `cd ~chooban`.

Comment: Do you mean: `sudo -u $different_user su -`?

Comment: @Andrew No! Don't `su` as that other user. Use the command you want to run as that user. For example, `sudo -u $different_user $command`

Comment: @DavidW I think I was trying to find a way to run multiple commands

Comment: You can run multiple commands with `sudo` in a single script if that's what you need. Using sudo and having it setup is the best way to go about it. Your commands can run in as that user without prompting. Otherwise, you have to sign in as that user, and that starts a new shell which means you have to manually run your commands. You want to do that automatically.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to:

1. execute **part of a bash script** as a different user
2. change to that user's $HOME directory

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8998789/27581), here's the adapted version of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

different_user=deploy

useradd -m -s /bin/bash "$different_user"

echo "Current user: $(whoami)"
echo "Current directory: $(pwd)"
echo

echo "Switching user to $different_user"
sudo -u "$different_user" -i /bin/bash - <<-'EOF'
    echo "Current user: $(id)"
    echo "Current directory: $(pwd)"
EOF
echo

echo "Switched back to $(whoami)"

different_user_home="$(eval echo ~"$different_user")"
echo "$different_user home directory: $different_user_home"
```

---

When you run it, you should get the following:

```
Current user: root
Current directory: /root

Switching user to deploy
Current user: uid=1003(deploy) gid=1003(deploy) groups=1003(deploy)
Current directory: /home/deploy

Switched back to root
deploy home directory: /home/deploy
```

Comment: You should use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as shebang.

Answer (score 2):

This works in Linux. Not sure how it behaves in other *nixes.

```
  getent passwd "${OTHER_USER}"|cut -d\: -f 6
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for this, but didn't want to impersonate a user to simply acquire a path!

`user_path=$(grep $username /etc/passwd|cut -f6 -d":");`

Now in your script, you can refer to `$user_path` in most cases would be `/home/username`

Assumes: You have previously set `$username` with the value of the intended users username.
Source: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/171782-cut-fields-etc-passwd-file-into-variables.html

Comment: The passwd file only contains local users, so this will not work for AD/LDAP integrated users. you should use the abstraction layer provided by 'getent' instead (see above example)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, and store it in a variable:

```
USER=somebody
USER_HOME="$(echo -n $(bash -c "cd ~${USER} && pwd"))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this question because I was looking for a way to do this in a bash script for OS X, hence /etc/passwd was out of the question, and my script was meant to be executed as root, therefore making the solutions invoking eval or bash -c dangerous as they allowed code injection into the variable specifying the username.

Here is what I found. It's simple and doesn't put a variable inside a subshell. However it does require the script to be ran by root as it sudos into the specified user account.

Presuming that $SOMEUSER contains a valid username:

```
echo "$(sudo -H -u "$SOMEUSER" -s -- "cd ~ && pwd")"
```

I hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't exist, `getent` will return an error.

Here's a small shell function that doesn't ignore the exit code of `getent`:

```
get_home() {
  local result; result="$(getent passwd "$1")" || return
  echo $result | cut -d : -f 6
}
```

Here's a usage example:

```
da_home="$(get_home missing_user)" || {
  echo 'User does NOT exist!'; exit 1
}

# Now do something with $da_home
echo "Home directory is: '$da_home'"
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of `getent passwd username` can be parsed with a Bash regular expression

```
OTHER_HOME="$(
  [[ "$(
    getent \
    passwd \
    "${OTHER_USER}"
  )" =~ ([^:]*:){5}([^:]+) ]] \
  && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have sudo active, just do:

```sh
sudo su - admin -c "echo \$HOME"
```

> NOTE: replace `admin` for the user you want to get the home directory