# Finding path to directories with a given name

Tags: bash, git-bash

I am trying to write a script which for any name given as an argument prints the list of paths to home directories of people with the name. Example:

```
$ shownames jakub anna 
/home/users/jakubo 
/home/students/j_luczka 
/home/students/kubeusz 
/home/students/jakub5z  
/home/students/qwertinx 
/home/users/lazinska 
/home/students/annalaz
```

**I am using Git Bash with files and directories on my local computer**

This is what I wrote so far:

```
for iter in "$@"; do find "$(pwd)"/home -type d -name "*$iter*"; done;
```

And as expected I get the full path.

```
$ ./shownames.sh jakub
/c/Users/User/students/home/users/jakubo
```

But what if I want to get only the /home/...... part? without the full c/Users.... so on part?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does the first sample show what you want? Can you put a sample of what you get? 
I didn't get the part 'C:/Users'..., are you using WSL? Can you show the result of $(pwd) (just type `pwd`) ?

Comment: I am using Git Bash with my own files and directories on my local computer. This is the result of pwd: /c/Users/User/students

Comment: Does stripping /Anything/until/home a viable answer? If so, some unix tools like `sed` could do this for you. I don't use git bash, do you have `sed` in it?

Comment: try this:
`for p in "/c/Users/User/students/home/users/jakubo" "/c/Users/User/students/home/users/anna" ; do echo "$p --> $(echo $p | cut -d/ -f 1,6-)" ;done`

Comment: or try this: `for p in "/c/Users/User/students/home/users/jakubo" "/c/Users/User/students/home/users/anna" ; do echo "$p --> ${p:22}" ;done`

Comment: Just use `find home` instead of `find "$(pwd)"/home`.

Comment: if you don't need the first `/` just use `find home` instead of `find "$(pwd)"/home` like @Socowi said

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get $HOME directory of different user in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504662/how-to-get-home-directory-of-different-user-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If removing unneeded strings is viable for you, just strip them:

Using bash substring (`${var:lenght}`) your shownames.sh will be:

```sh
for iter in "$@"; do find "$(pwd)"/home -type d -name "*$iter*"; done | while read p; do echo ${p:22}; done
```

results:

```
root@fd416de714ab:/c/Users/User/students# ./shownames.sh anna jakub
/home/users/anna
/home/users/jakubo
root@fd416de714ab:/c/Users/User/students#
```

Using cut tool, your shownames.sh will be:

```sh
for iter in "$@"; do find "$(pwd)"/home -type d -name "*$iter*"; done | cut -d/ -f 1,6-
```

results will be the same

Also, the $(pwd)/ seems unnecessary:

```sh
for iter in "$@"; do find ./home -type d -name "*$iter*"; done | while read p; do echo ${p:1}; done
```

Comment: You can not be sure the home directory of a user contains the user id in its path.

Comment: This answer is very restrict to the question, I just explain how to remove unneeded parts @LéaGris

Comment: Also, he uses gitbash (windows), if he was using linux, I could get the home directories from /etc/passwd, but it's not that case @LéaGris

Comment: As an aside, if you omit the completely unnecessary `$(pwd)` you only have to remove `.` from the beginning of each result.