# Running du against the home directory of a user whose name came from a variable

Tags: bash

Hello I have one bash script like this :

```
readarray -t a < /home/z/Systeme/Sonde/dataUser.txt 
len=${#a[@]}
for((i=0; i<$len; i++));
do
   du -sh ~${a[i]}
done
```

The file dataUser .txt now only contain username of the session in this case only z is write in the file.

In the prompt when I do du -sh ~z
The result is  :
415M home/z
So this is working

But when I start my script the prompt display :
du : cannot access 'z' : No file or directory of this type.
I think this is because of the type of {a[i]}
How can I solve this ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: `home/z` is a path relative to your current directly. Use an abosolute path if you want to it to work the same from any directory.

Comment: Note that `var=user; echo ~$var` is **not** the same as `echo ~user`. Tilde expansion happens **before** parameter expansion, so it can't take advantage of variable contents. Nothing discussed here is in any way specific to `du` -- all this processing happens in the shell before `du` is started at all.

Comment: (tagging note: Keep tags down to things that are specific to the question; this should only be tagged "du" if you can't cause the same problem with non-du commands; should only be tagged "linux" if you can't cause the problem on non-Linux operating systems; should only tag "arrays" if it doesn't happen when the username comes from a string variable; etc).

Comment: In addition to the linked duplicate also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53219743/14122) answer on [How to get $HOME directory of a different user in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504662/how-to-get-home-directory-of-different-user-in-bash-script)