# Setting up Shell Script for Vagrant Setup

Tags: shell, vagrant

Trying to write a shell script to setup my server environment on Ubuntu through Vagrant and am running into a problem where the script ends unexpectedly. I added the path to the shell script in Vagrant's provision config option.

Vagrant:

```
# Specify our provision script
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "scripts/bootstrap.sh"
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Install dependencies for Ruby
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev software-properties-common

# Setting up rbenv
echo 'Setting up rbenv'
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL
```

After running, I expect the repository to be cloned into the .rbenv folder and to have rbenv added to $PATH in ~/.bashrc along with the rbenv init function evaluated and put into ~/.bashrc. However, when the script is executed on Vagrant's provision step I end up with the script just cloning the git repository and then terminating without executing anything else in my script.

Output:

```
==> default: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
==> default: Setting up rbenv
==> default: Cloning into '.rbenv'...
```

And then the script terminates and ~/.bashrc is left unchanged. I was wondering how I can change my shell script so that it will perform the action I want (which is adding rbenv to ~/.bashrc). Any ideas?

Comment: Is the script executed in the context of the _current user_? Could it be that `~` points elsewhere when the script runs? For debugging, add the following to your script and capture its _stderr_ output as well: `PS4='>$LINENO: '; set -xv`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mklement0 said, the script does not run as the `vagrant` user: it runs as `root`.

If you want to run the script as the `vagrant` user you need `privileged: false`.

```
config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false, path: "scripts/bootstrap.sh"
```

As mklement0 said: use set `-xv` to debug your provisioning scripts.

If you want to run as another user, don't forget that `su user` *won't* work: [How do I use su to execute the rest of the bash script as that user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988249/how-do-i-use-su-to-execute-the-rest-of-the-bash-script-as-that-user)

Answer (score 2):

If you want execute some script like vagrant user, try this.

```
 su vagrant -l -c "echo Hello world"
```