# sudo won't work in shell

Tags: shell, sudo

I have a problem with the following command

`sudo -u ${USER} -H sh -c "bash ${START_SCRIPT}"`

I can exclude errors with the START_SCRIPT, since

`bash ${START_SCRIPT}`

works excellent.

I think there must be a problem with the sudo-syntax, but I can't find the answer. Everywhere (e.g. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988249/how-do-i-use-su-to-execute-the-rest-of-the-bash-script-as-that-user), answer by Kimvais or the sudo manpages) suggest the formatation I used above.

`USER=some_user
START_SCRIPT=/some/long/path/start.sh`

I can only guess that it has to do with the long path or that I miss any arguments for the sudo-command.

In [this thread](http://sudo%20-H%20-u%20otheruser%20bash%20-c%20'echo%20%22I%20am%20$USER,%20with%20uid%20$UID%22') I read:

`sudo -H -u otheruser bash -c 'echo "I am $USER, with uid $UID"'`

That works perfectly, but neither

`sudo -H -u otheruser bash -c '${START_SCRIPT}'`

nor

`sudo -H -u otheruser -c 'bash "${START_SCRIPT}"'`

works.

Can anyone help me please or at least give a hint?

Comment: Why would you run `sh` just to run `bash`?

Comment: You cannot have spaces around the equals sign in the assignments.  If you have those errors in your actual script, both `USER` and `START_SCRIPT` will be empty variables (and you should get error messages saying `USER: command not found` etc).

Comment: Hi tripleee! Thanks for your input. There are no spaces, sorry. I've edited the thread.

Comment: `sudo -H -u otheruser -c 'bash "${START_SCRIPT}"'` is also a syntax error (`c` is not a valid option for `sudo`) but `sudo -H -u otheruser bash "${START_SCRIPT}"` should work if `START_SCRIPT` really contains the value you expect.

Comment: Also, if `START_SCRIPT` has a proper valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) , simply `sudo -H -u otheruser $START_SCRIPT` should work as well (or better).

Comment: Single quotes around `'$START_SCRIPT'` will prevent variable substitution, so you will get the literal string inside the single quotes, not the value of the shell variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single quotes in

```
sudo -H -u otheruser bash -c '${START_SCRIPT}'
```

prevent the shell from expanding the `$`. Simply use double quotes:

```
sudo -H -u otheruser bash -c "${START_SCRIPT}"
```