# Set variable in bash script sudo with heredoc

Tags: bash, sudo, su

I'm trying to run a script which switches users (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24696790/1013719)). I'm unable to set a variable within this. I've tried many things but the most basic is:

```
sudo -u other_user bash << EOF
V=test
echo "${V}"
EOF
```

More realistically I am doing something similar to the following:

```
sudo -u other_user bash << EOF
cd
V=$(ls)
echo "${V}"
EOF
```

Every time I try to use the variable `V` it is unset. How can I set a variable?

Comment: Can't test on my current environment, but I'm pretty sure `"${V}"` is expanded in your outer shell rather than in the other user's. Try escaping the `$`

Comment: @Aaron that's it! Convert to an answer and I'll accept

Comment: Protip: Just like you can print variable values to try to debug a script, you can print the contents of here docs to make sure you're passing the right data. Simply replace `sudo -u other_user bash` with `cat` and you'll see what your shell is getting and why it behaves like that

Comment: @RyanHaining Charles Duffy's answer is probably better, might as well accept this one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To suppress all expansions within the heredoc, quote the sigil -- that is, `<<'EOF'`, not `<<EOF`:

```
sudo -u other_user bash -s <<'EOF'
cd
v=$(ls)      # aside: don't ever actually use ls programmatically
             #        see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs
echo "$v"    # aside: user-defined variables should have lowercase names; see
             #        http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html
             #        fourth paragraph ("the name space of environment variable names
             #        containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications.")
EOF
```

If you want to pass variables through, pass them after the `-s`, and refer to them positionally from in the heredoc script (as `$1`, `$2`, etc).