# ssh-add on command argument to su

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, sh

I want to start a docker container that adds a ssh key at startup :

My entrypoint looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

service ssh start

su anotherUser -s /bin/bash -c "eval \"$(ssh-agent)\" && ssh-add /Keys/id_rsa"
```

I've seen many posts that use `sudo`, but I do not have `sudo` available. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1988265/8325761) solution but at the startup it shows me :

> [....] Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd 7[ ok 8.
> Agent pid 36
> Error connecting to agent: Permission denied

But when I execute the same lines at the promp everythings is ok :

> xxx# su anotherUser
> anotherUser@xxx:~$ eval $(ssh-agent)
> Agent pid 47
> anotherUser@xxx:~$ ssh-add /keys/id_rsa
> Identity added: /keys/id_rsa (yyy@yyy-HP-EliteBook-850-G4)

Comment: could you try with `'eval "$(ssh-agent)" && ssh-add /Keys/id_rsa'` instead ?

Comment: yes it works thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `ssh-agent` before `su` runs. The `$` needs to be escaped so that the literal command substitution is passed to `bash` for execution.

```
su anotherUser -s /bin/bash -c 'eval $(ssh-agent) && ssh-add /Keys/id_rsa'
```

---

(Untested; probably needs more details about how the container is run and why `ssh-add` needs to be run as a different user.)

It may be simpler, though, to run your entry point *with* `ssh-agent`. For example,

```
# In the Dockerfile...
ENTRYPOINT ["ssh-agent", "entry.sh"]
```

Inside `entry.sh`, your environment will already have access to the agent.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

service ssh start

su anotherUser -s ssh-add /Keys/id_rsa
```

Comment: the first solution works fine but not the second ... I think there's an error here `su anotherUser -s ssh-add /Keys/id_rsa`