# How to use pbrun to run commands in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, pbrun

We currently use pbrun to switch user and then run our commands.

For ex.

```
$ pbrun /bin/su - enterprisedb
Last login: Wed Nov 10 15:44:43 MST 2021 on pts/5
[enterprisedb@server_name ~]$ whoami
enterprisedb
[enterprisedb@server_name ~]$
```

Below is how my pbrun policy is defined.

```
[ RunAs User ]       [ Command ]
root                 /bin/su - enterprisedb
```

How can I script it? I want to run a command (for ex. whoami) using enterprisedb user from my current user(ADS) on that server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988249/how-do-i-use-su-to-execute-the-rest-of-the-bash-script-as-that-user